# How do I make my Discord Bot reply a same answer for similar messages? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a Discord bot. I needed a solution for questions like this: `Who are you` or `who are you`.

The above sentences may seem similar but are case sensitive, and I want my bot to reply the same answer to a few similar questions like I showed above. This is What I tried:

```js
import Discord from 'discord.js'
import { Client, Intents } from 'discord.js'

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("Log In Successful!!")
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'hello', 'hey') {
    msg.reply("hi");
  }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

But when I run it and write the command, it repeats the reply several times.

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that is causing the multiple replies is this one:

```js
if (msg.content === 'hello', 'hey'){
```

Your syntax is slightly off and the 'hey' is not part of the statement like you want it to be. The 'hey' evaluates to `true` which triggers the if statement's code a second time.

To fix it, you may want to have an array of responses, and check if the user's message is in the array
(note the `.toLowerCase()` means you don't have to worry about capital letters):

```js
greetings = ['hello', 'hey', 'hi']
if (greentings.indexOf(msg.content.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    // the message is in the array - run your code here
}
```

Comment: `.indexOf(x) > -1` isn't really needed, just use `.includes(x)`

Answer (score 1):

You can group similar questions in an array and use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the question is in that array. You can also make it case-insensitive by using [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). Something like this:

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
  const group = [
    'how are you',
    'how you doin',
    'you alright',
  ]
  if (group.includes(msg.content.toLowerCase())) {
    msg.reply('hi');
  }
})
```